# Gsql not executing while constructing query

Tags: sql, grails, groovy

I want to fire an update query , normally using groovy we do something like :

```
sql.executeUpdate("update MYTABLE l set field1  where l.id = ${someobj.id}")
```

The above works perfectly but my problem is that i dont know ahead how many parameters i need to update. So i made a function which returns the 
properttoudate1 = value1 , propertytoupdate2 = value2 .. and so on..
Then i modified the above query to

```
sql.executeUpdate("update MYTABLE l set ${makeQueryString(propertiesToUpdate)} where l.id = ${someobj.id}")
```

Now it gives me the error::

```
com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ''PROPERTY1 = 1' where l.id = 'PROPERTVALUE1'' at line 1
```

ANY IDEAS ??

Comment: Why are you using raw SQL instead of GORM for this?

Comment: whats the return value of ${makeQueryString(propertiesToUpdate)} ?

Comment: @StevieG : ${makeQueryString(propertiesToUpdate)} returns FIELDNAME1 = VALUE1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to tell Groovy that the fieldname is a static, and shouldnt be replaced with `?` [by using `Sql.expand`](http://groovy.codehaus.org/api/groovy/sql/Sql.html#expand%28java.lang.Object%29):

```
sql.executeUpdate("update MYTABLE l set ${Sql.expand(makeQueryString(propertiesToUpdate))} where l.id = ${someobj.id}")
```

Comment: Worked!! thanks. Probably you can shed some more light on the issue.

Comment: Yes just read it. Thanks. I thought that its a GString issue.

Comment: @NikhilSharma No, it's Groovy's Sql class trying to be too helpful and turning your first parameter `FIELDNAME1 = VALUE1` into a `?` parameter of a `PreparedStatement` (which is then invalid Sql :-)